# Load HTML Header with JQuery .load() or setting innerHTML to string?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, web

For a while I have been using the JQuery `.load()` function to load HTML files into my header and footer elements. I have always had a problem with how long it would take before the header showed up. Recently, I switched to having a function that inserts a string of HTML into the `innerHTML`. I am wondering, is there actually any advantage to this? Or is it the loading of another `GET` request that takes all the time (the new script is a .js file on my server). Any suggestions on how to optimize? Thanks!

Comment: those are really 2 unrelated concepts. load() is an async ajax request that dumps the response output into an html element, whereas innerHTML is just a property of an html element. Apples and oranges

Comment: I'm not really asking about the functions themselves, I am asking about the workflow. Is it faster to do an Ajax query and whatever the load function does, or to get a .js file and insert a long string into an html element?

Comment: Usually the data in question has a dynamic component to it, so the ajax method would be appropriate (rather than hardcoding static data into a js file). However, it really depends on your use case and goals, but dynamic data almost always is brought into a page (once it's loaded) using ajax or fetch